# How to extend argument spread types?

Tags: typescript, electron

I am trying to have handler inherit argument types from function to avoid hard coding duplicate types.

This is what I have so far… doesn’t work but I believe it illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

```js
const generate = async (foo: string, bar: string) => {
  …
}

ipcMain.handle("generate", async (...args) => {
  const { event, ...otherArgs } = { ...args }
  return generate(...otherArgs)
})
```

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out… TypeScript is amazing!

```js
ipcMain.handle(
  "generate",
  async (event, ...args: Parameters<typeof generate>) => {
    return generate(...args)
  }
)
```